# Is there a recommended approach for object creation in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, object, architecture, request

I know that in PHP objects are created for each request and destroyed when the processing is finished.

And in Java, depending on configuration, objects can remain in memory and be either associated with a single user (through server sessions) or shared between multiple users.

**Is there a general rule for this in Node.js?**

I see many projects instantiating all app objects in the entry script, in which case they will be shared between requests.

Others will keep object creation inside functions, so AFAIK objects are destroyed after processing each request.

What are the downsides of each approach? Obviously, things like memory usage and information sharing should be considered, but are there any other things specific to Node.js that we should pay attention to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript has no such thing as objects that are tied to a given request.  The language is garbage collected and all objects are garbage collected when there are no more references to them and no code can reach them.  This has absolutely nothing to do with request handlers.

> so AFAIK objects are destroyed after processing each request.

No.  The lifetime of objects in Javascript has absolutely nothing to do with requests.

Instead, think of function scopes.  If you create an object in a request handler and use it in that request handler and don't store it somewhere that creates a long lasting reference to the object, then just like ANY other function in Javascript, when that request handler function finishes and returns and has no more asynchronous operations still in-flight, then any objects created within that function that are not stored in some other scope will be cleaned up by the garbage collector.

It is the exact same rules for a request handler as it is for any other function call in the language.

So, please forget anything you know about PHP as its request-specific architecture will only mess you up in Javascript/node.js.  There is no such thing in node.js.

Instead, think of a node.js server as one, long running process with a garbage collector.  All objects that are created will be garbage collected when they are no longer reachable by live code (e.g. there are no live references to them that any code can get to).  This is the same whether the object is created at startup of the server, in a request handler on the server, in a recurring timer on the server or any other event on the server.  The language has one garbage collector that works the same everywhere and has no special behavior for server requests.

The usual way to do things in a node.js server is to create objects that are local variables in the request handler function (or in any functions that it calls) or maybe even occasionally assigned as properties of the `request` or `response` objects (middleware will often do this).  Since everything is scoped to a function call in the request chain when that function call is done, the things you created as local variables in those functions will become eligible for garbage collection.

In general, you do not use many higher scoped variables outside the request handler except for purposeful long term storage (session state, database connections, or other server-wide state).

> Is there a general rule for this in Node.js?

Not really in the sense you were asking since Javascript is really just about the scope that a variable is declared in and then garbage collection from there, but I will offer some guidelines down below.

If data is stored in a scope higher than the request handler (module scope or global scope), then it probably lasts for a long time because there is a lasting reference that future request handlers can access so it will not be garbage collected.

If objects are created and used within a request handler and not attached to any higher scope, then they will be garbage collected by the language automatically when the function is done executing.

Session frameworks typically create a specific mechanism for storing server-side state that persists on the server on a per-user basis.  A popular node.js session manager, `express-session` does exactly this.  There, you follow the rules for the session framework for how to store or remove data from each user's session.  This isn't really a language feature as it is specific library built in the language.  Even the session manage relies on the garbage collector.   Data persists in the session manager when desired because there are lasting references to the data to make it available to future requests.

node.js has no such thing as "per-user" or "per-request" data built into the language or the environment.  A session manager builds "per-user" data artificially by making persistent data that can be requested or accessed on a per-user basis.

Some general rules for node.js:

1. Define in your head and your design which data is local to a specific request handler, which data is meant for long term store, which data is meant for user-specific sessions.  You should be very clear about  that.
2. Don't ever put request-specific variables into any higher scope that any other request handler can access unless these are purposeful shared variables that are meant to be accessed by multiple requests.  Accidentally sharing variables between requests creates concurrency issues and race conditions and very hard-to-track-down server bugs as one request may write to that variable in doing it's work and then another request may come along and also write to it, trouncing what the first request was working on.  Keep these kind of request-specific variables local to the request handler (local to the function for the request handler) so that can never happen.
3. If you are storing data for long term use (beyond the lifetime of a specific request) which would generally mean storing it in a module scoped variable or in a global scoped variable (should generally not use global scoped variables), then be very, very careful about how the data is stored and accessed to avoid race conditions or inconsistent state that might mess up some other request handler reading/writing to that data.  node.js makes this simpler because it runs your Javascript as single threaded, but once your request handler makes some sort of asynchronous function call (like a database call), then other request handlers get to run so you have to be careful about modifications to shared state across asynchronous boundaries.

> I see many projects instantiating all app objects in the entry script, in which case they will be shared between requests.

In the example of an web server using the Express framework, there is one `app` object that all requests have access to.  The only request-specific variables are the `request` and `response` objects that are created by the web server framework and passed into your request handler.  Those will be unique to each new request.  All other server state is accessible by all requests.

> What are the downsides of each approach?

If you're asking for a comparison of the Apache/PHP web server model to the node.js/Express web server model, that's a really giant question.  They are very different architectures and the topic has been widely discussed and debated before.  I'd suggest you do some searching on that topic, read what has been previously written and then ask a more specific question about things you don't quite understand or need some clarification on.